# video and graphic option missing in amd catalyst control center

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I was struggling with an issue of catalyst control center could not be started there are currently no setting that can be configured using AMD CCC.

So I contacted Dell CC and he sent me a link to download the latest AMD CCC driver (release date 4/2014). I downloaded and installed them. My driver is AMD Raedon HD8730M version 13.250.31.0.

The above issue is solved but new arises. In AMD CCC the options video, games and power are missing. Don't know what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing Preferences->Advanced view solved that for me :)
(was googling for "AMD CCC tabs missing" for a while before that)